# Number of cubes from sphere

Tags: geometry

Reference : [2nd question](http://www.placementexpress.com/collegepdf/amazon_mock_d.pdf) - 
 .

> From a spherical ball of 10cm radius, how many complete cubes of 5cm
>   side can be extracted out, if sphere cannot be molten

What I have tried.

> - Volume of sphere = $\frac43 \pi 10^3$
> - volume of cube = $5^3$
>
> So find how many $5^3$ can appear in $\frac43 \pi 10^3$.

But I guess this is wrong and the statement *sphere cannot be molten*. makes this answer different. How this statement affect the answer. Please give pointers on what is the approach of solving this.

Comment: Smash it into fine dust, then recompress into cubes!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution with $13$ cubes, $6$ of them colored blue:

[image]

According to my calculations the blue squares fit into a circle of radius $r\doteq6.44$, and $r^2+7.5^2\doteq 97.754<100$.

Comment: (+1) Notes on verification, using unit cubes and a ball of radius $2$: It suffices to check that the "extreme" vertices $(1.5, 1, 0.5)$ (in the middle layer), and, for some positive $a$ to be determined, $(0.5, 1 + a, 1.5)$, $(1, a - 1, 1.5)$ (in the upper layer) have magnitude at most $2$. A bit of algebra shows $a$ "works" iff $|a + 1| \leq \sqrt{6}/2$ and $|a - 1| \leq \sqrt{3}/2$. Since $(\sqrt{6} + \sqrt{3})/2 \approx 2.09077 > 2$, there exists a positive $a$ with the desired properties.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Nice solution. Which software did you use to make that pitcture?

Comment: @mrprottolo: "Canvas". They just brought out a new version for Mac OS.

Answer (score 2):

Your computation yields only an upper bound of $33.51\ldots$ (so actually of $33$), but that is by sheer volume (so "with melting").
As the suggested answer show, this bound seems to be *way* too big.

Arranging $8$ cubes in a $2\times 2\times 2$ pattern produces a larger cube of side length $10$ and diameter $10\sqrt 3\approx17.3$, which therefore fits easily into a ball of diameter $20$.
Hence from the suggested answers, the largest seems to be appropriate.

However, could one not possibly extract $9$ or more cubes (a non-available answer)?

---

At least the *straighforward*, but larger step to $12$ cubes is not possible: An arrangement of $2\times 2\times 3$ cubes has a diameter of $5\cdot\sqrt 17\approx 20.6>20$. But $9$ cubes appear are possible: Take the $2\times 2\times 2$ arrangement and at one cube on the top, centered. The diameter of this object is $\sqrt{7.5^2+7.5^2+15^2}=\frac{15}2\sqrt{6}\approx18.4<20 $.
A sufficiently small diameter alone is not sufficient: for example a triangle of diameter $1$ does not fit into a circle of diameter $1$.
However, we can actually position our $2\times 2\times 2$ thing so that it touches the ball boundary at the "bottom"; then the lower vertices are  $\sqrt{10^2-5^2-5^2}$ below the ball center; similarly, a single cube pushed to to "top" has its higher vertices $\sqrt{10^2-2.5^2-2.5^2}$ above the ball center.
From
$$ \sqrt{10^2-5^2-5^2}+\sqrt{10^2-2.5^2-2.5^2}\approx 16.4>15$$
we see that everything fits, even with a safety gap of $\approx 1.4$.

Even a block of two cubes, pushed as high up as possible ends up at $\sqrt{10^2-5^2-2.5^2}$ and then
$$ \sqrt{10^2-5^2-5^2}+\sqrt{10^2-5^2-2.5^2}\approx 15.4>15$$
shows that we can place $10$ cubes.

Comment: I understood the explanation and answer can be 8. But can you please explain more on how 9 is possible.

Comment: I think that you can extract at least $12$ cubes, because you can take a rectangular parallelepiped of lenghts $10 \times 15  \times  10$ cm, that fits in the sphere.

Comment: @mrprottolo, thanks for your comment. I thought this is a simple question, but now looks a difficult one. What is the standard way of solving this type question?

Comment: There is not a standard way, the best thing you can do is to draw a picture, make a supposition (for example that $9$ is possible ) and try to find an arrangement of the cubes. The problems of finding the maximum or the minimum are usually hard porblems, even in this case, $12$ is possible, but maybe there is a better solution.

Comment: thanks for your guidance  @mrprottolo

Comment: @mrprottolo No, this arrangement does not fit, see my edited answer ($\sqrt{ 17}>4$). It migh be that a less regular arrangement of 12 cubes *could* fit, though

Comment: What is the definition of diameter you are using for non-spherical objects? I always understood it to be the maximum distance between two points in the object (which would make the diameter of a cube $\sqrt 3$ rather than $\sqrt 2$) but it seems clear from what you write that  you mean something different.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen you are right, I did the wrong calculations.

Comment: @BenMillwood No, instead it is clear that I miscalculated :)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: the thing that made me suspect something other than a miscalculation was your comment about triangles not fitting inside circles, but then I thought about it a bit more and I realised it's actually true as stated after all, silly me.